# Is there any way to create Encrypting FileSystem certificate mannually?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I want to create an encrypting filesystem certificate. Is there any way to create it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the `User Accounts` control panel under `User Accounts and Family Safety`. On the left, select `Manage your file encryption certificates`. In the wizard, select `Next`. Check `Create new certificate`. Then hit `Next` again.

Comment: Is it available in Windows 7 Home premium ? I could not see anything like "manage your file encryption certificates" under User Accounts in windows 7 Home premium.

Comment: I don't have a home premium machine handy to test on, but it should be. Are you sure you selected `User Accounts`?

Comment: yes i selected control panel > User accounts.